# Read file and dynamically modify variables

Tags: javascript

I have the following code inside my routes.dart file:

```
final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = {
  '/': (context) => HomeScreen(),
  '/login': (context) => LoginScreen(),
  '/home': (context) => HomeScreen(),
  '/test': (context) => TestScreen()
};
```

Now I would like to be able to read this file like a text file and automatically append or remove lines from my routes map. I am not sure where or how to start.

Comment: Perhaps you have legitimate use case for this, but I'm curious what it is. It seems odd to programmatically modify a code file rather than the data structure it ends up being at runtime.

Comment: Do you want to simply modify routes dynamically? Because rewriting the code file would not be the way to do that.

Comment: Yes when a file is added/removed/renamed in a specific folder I want to update this map.